# Issue passing parameters using f:viewParam

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces, actionlistener

I have a JSF page that displays numerous data items pulled from a DB given an account. The page has a SelectOneMenu that lists all accounts in the DB to choose from and a commandButton to trigger reloading the page with the newly selected account. My issue is when I click the commandButton the page reloads but is not taking the newly selected account. The "else" in method pullData() is being executed.

My JSF page:

```
<f:metadata>
    <f:viewParam name="account" value="#{accountAnalysisBean.account}" />   
    <f:viewParam name="start" value="#{accountAnalysisBean.start}" />   
    <f:viewParam name="end" value="#{accountAnalysisBean.end}" />       
    <f:event type="preRenderView" listener="#{accountAnalysisBean.pullData}" />  
</f:metadata>

<h:form>
    <p:panelGrid columns="6">
    <f:facet name="header"> 
        <p:selectOneMenu id="pickAccount" value="#{accountAnalysisBean.pickAccount}" required="true">            
            <f:selectItems value="#{editAccountBean.allAccounts}" />                            
            </p:selectOneMenu>        
            <p:calendar id="start" value="#{accountAnalysisBean.start}" />              

        <p:calendar id="end" value="#{accountAnalysisBean.end}" />          

        <p:commandButton value="Get Account" actionListener="#{accountAnalysisBean.updateAccount}" /> 
                <f:param name="start" value="#{accountAnalysisBean.start}"/>
                <f:param name="end" value="#{accountAnalysisBean.end}"/>
                <f:param name="account" value="#{accountAnalysisBean.pickAccount}"/>
            </p:commandButton>
        </f:facet>
    </p:panelGrid>
</h:form>
```

My Bean:

```
@ManagedBean  
@RequestScoped

public class AccountAnalysisBean {

private String account = "";   
private String id = "";   
private String pickAccount = "";     
private Date start;   
private Date end;  

//----getters and setters----  

public void pullData() {  
    if (account != "") {  
        //pull various fields from database given account value  
    } else {  
        //set default null values           
        }   
}  

public String updateAccount(ActionEvent actionEvent) {  

fix = DAOFactory.getInstance("fix_site2.jdbc");  
datalist = fix.getMyDataDAO();    
account = datalist.findAccountID(pickAccount); //returns an ID from a DB given account selected from menu    

return "/AccountAnalysis.xhtml?includeViewParams=true";  

}  

//remainder of code omitted for clarity  

}
```

I am using JSF 2.2 and PrimeFaces 4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's walk through what's likely happening here:

- `<f:viewParam/>` will set the value in your `AccountAnalysisBean` bean on initial page load, using the defined setter
- As soon as the page is done loading, `AccountAnalysisBean` is destroyed: it's a `@RequestScoped` bean.
- So, as at the time you're clicking on your commandButton, you're starting with a fresh copy of `AccountAnalysisBean` with nothing in it.

---

**Consider:**

- Making `AccountAnalysisBean` a `@ViewScoped` bean
- Getting rid of that `actionListener` and use the `action` attribute instead. Going by the code sample you have here, you don't really need it.